# C++ Vector removing specific items, but segfaults

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

all. I'm working on software to block ads using the system's hosts file, but on to the code.

I have a custom class `HostEntry` that contains necessary information such as the destination host, the host to block, the destination host's ip... etc.

In the HostsManager class, it keeps a vector to keep track of all the hosts added. In order to block a host completely, I must add `example.com` AND `www.example.com`, but when I iterate over the vector it will only delete the entry starting with "www." and leaves the one without. If you try to delete it a second time (with only the entry missing the "www.") it segfaults, and I don't know why.

```
void HostsManager::delHost(std::string blockedhost) {
    strip(blockedhost);
    string tmp; // yes I know it's not great practice to do it like this, but it was for debug reasons
    for (vector<HostEntry>::iterator viter = hosts.begin(); viter != hosts.end(); ++viter) {
        tmp = viter->getHost();
        if (tmp == blockedhost || tmp == ("www." + blockedhost)) {
            viter = hosts.erase(viter);
        }
    }
}
```

An example call to that specific function:

```
HostsManager mgr;
mgr.delHost("mysite.com"); // this deletes "www.mysite.com" but not "mysite.com" - whether or not you call delHost() with the "www." prefix
mgr.delHost("mysite.com"); // if you call it a second time, it segfaults O.o
```

Help with this would be GREATLY appreciated.

EDIT: I assigned the value returned from the call to erase() to viter, same result. I still have no idea why this is happening.

If you need all the code, it's at http://paste.pocoo.org/show/363051/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally better to use `std::remove_if` to delete multiple items from a vector; it runs in linear time instead of quadratic and avoids having to worry about iterator invalidation.

Might look something like this:

```
hosts.erase(std::remove_if(hosts.begin(), 
                           hosts.end(), 
                           [&blockedhost](const HostEntry& entry) {
                               return entry.getHost() == blockedhost || 
                                      entry.getHost() == "www." + blockedhost;
                           }),
            hosts.end());
```

You can accomplish a similar thing without C++0x lambdas via a struct to compare with:

```
struct RemoveBlockedHost {
    RemoveBlockedHost(const std::string& s): blockedHost(s) {}
    bool operator () (const HostEntry& entry) {
        return entry.getHost() == blockedHost || entry.getHost() == "www." + blockedHost;
    }
    const std::string& blockedHost;
};

hosts.erase(std::remove_if(hosts.begin(), hosts.end(), RemoveBlockedHost(blockedhost)), hosts.end());
```

Comment: I wish to delete only two items - both containing a certain host, one with a www. prefix, one without. Would that delete only host entries containing `blockedhost` ? it appears as if it will delete from the first index of blockedhost to the end.

Comment: assuming I have not messed up my syntax, it should only erase the items you want. `remove_if` moves all the items to the end that match the predicate; it then erases from the returned iterator to the end of the vector.

Comment: Aaaah, ok. Also, alternatively is http://paste.pocoo.org/show/363058/  also acceptable syntax? I will probably use your lambada example, though.

Comment: I imagine that would work, although it's not really the most elegant solution to make a copy of the entire container without the entries you want to erase.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting items from the vector you are iterating over! You want to set `viter` to the value returned from `erase`. See the C++ doc for [vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/)

Comment: Aaah, thank you. I completely forgot it's bad to modify the list/vector you're iterating on. I'll try that, and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Alas, it did not work. I have the exact same problem. Code on post is now updated.

Answer (score 1):

When you erase a vector member, it invalidates the iterator.

Std::lists are designed to allow you to delete in the middle like this without invalidating your iterator. Thus, for this specific operation, it would allow the simplest code.

However, a vector might still be better overall IF performance is an issue. Only if the list has a sufficiently large number of members and you are deleting in the middle enough would the list see a performance benefit for the less complex code it would allow.

Comment: Indeed, I plan to have 200+ items. I think a vector will work, but using `viter = hosts.erase(viter)` still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`viter` is not valid anymore after you modified the collection that `viter` iterates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error from the code. I think you should run your debug version, and put breakpoints at delHost(). Step through it to find out where causes the seg fault problem.